# How to use hitTestPoint when a movie is scaled

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Google says that:

```
displayObject.hitTest(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY, true)
```

is the way to test for the mouse being over a DisplayObject. This works if my movie is displayed at 100% scale. But if maximise my browser window so the Flash movie changes scale, it all goes to pieces.

Does anyone have a way to fix this, please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally use:

```
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, functionName);
```

But, if you have a specific reason for using the hitTest method, than you may want to look into converting your point from a global to a local MovieClip coordinate. Once you scale a MovieClip, it's x-y coordinates are no longer mapped 1-to-1 to the stage coordinates. BUT, you can make Flash figure out which coordinate you ARE talking about by using:

```
 yourMovieClip.globalToLocal( yourTestPoint )); // [x=-10, y=0]
```

Here is the related link with all the documentation...

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html

You may also want to take a look at the "hitTestObject()" method which does the same thing as hitTestPoint, only using the entire object... no points!

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you say, the issue is that when the movie is scaled up (in a maximised browser window say), the co-ordinates of my outermost movie clip don't match those of the stage. So, seemingly contrary to the docs, I need to use the co-ordinate space of my outermost DisplayObject for the hit test, as below:

    var point:Point = new Point (e.stageX, e.stageY);
    point = outerMostDisplayObject.globalToLocal(point);
    if (hitArea.hitTestPoint(point.x, point.y, true)) {}

Comment: In this case, the documentation is plainly wrong. The x,y are in the *root* coordinates space, NOT *Stage*!